# why the django GET method is not getting called properly

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a very basic GET method that is suppose to fetch token field from a table based on id, and comp as seen below

```
class merge(APIView):
 def get(self, request):
        id = request.GET.get('id')
        comp = request.GET.get('comp')
        queryset = tablename.objects.filter(id=id, comp=comp)
        token_instance = queryset.first()
        if token_instance:
            acnt_token = token_instance.token
            serializer = AcToknSerializers(queryset, many=True)
            return acnt_token, serializer.data
        else:
            return None, []
```

serializer class

```
class AcToknSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = tablename
        fields = ['token']
```

below is how I am calling in browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/syncall/0aabf5ee/75v20375n02
```

I am geting below error

```
        RecursionError at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comp-info/syncall/0aabf5ee/75v20375n02
        maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comp-info/syncall/0aabf5ee/75v20375n02
Django Version: 5.0.1
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value:    
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception Location: C:\Users\AmiteshSahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging\__init__.py, line 424, in usesTime
```

How can I fix this? Please suggest

Comment: Can you add the complete error traceback?

Comment: RecursionError at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/erp/comp-info/syncall/0aabf5ee/75v20375n02
   maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
 
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/erp/comp-info/syncall/0aabf5ee/75v20375n02
Django Version: 5.0.1
Exception Type: RecursionError
Exception Value: 
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Exception Location: C:\Users\AmiteshSahay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\logging\__init__.py, line 424, in usesTime

Comment: adding in the main body as well

Comment: we can close this , as I had two  method with same name "get". However, the error is different. Will open new query for that

Answer (score 1):

```
class Merge(APIView):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      rest of your code....!
```

Pascal Case is used for the classes also called camel case, is the best practice to define classes.